# Express не видит значения формы

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

При отправке формдаты req.body express'а пустой.
index.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const credentials = require("./credentials.js");
const app = express();
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({defaultLayout:"main"})

app.engine('handlebars',handlebars.engine);
app.set("view engine","handlebars");
app.set("view cache","handlebars");
app.set("port",process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(cookieParser(credentials.cookieSecret))

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    let data = req.cookies.value ? req.cookies.value : 0;
    res.render("form",{value:data});
})
app.get("/send",function(req,res){
    res.type("text/plain");
    res.status(200);
    res.send("rpf;");
})
app.get("/about",function(req,res){
    res.render("about");
})
app.post("/register",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("Works!");
})
app.use(function(req,res){
    res.status(404);
    res.render("404");
})
app.use(function(err,req,res,next){
    res.status(500);
    res.send("500 - Ошибка Сервера");
})
app.listen(app.get('port'),function(){
    console.log("The server is working")
})
```

main.js

```js
const form = document.querySelector(".main-form");
form.onsubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(form);
    fetch(`${form.action}`,{
        "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest",
        "method":"POST",
        body:data
    }).then(response => response.text()).then(val => console.log(val));
}
```

form.handlebars

```html
<form class="main-form" action="/register" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Please write down your information.</legend>
        <input type="text" name="Value"/>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Send form!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что клиент передает данные формы именно в формате URL Encoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это происходит из-за того, что вы отправляете данные как `Form Data` (`multipart/formdata`), но `body-parser` не умеет работать с таким типом, на [GitHub](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) пишут:

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:

Исправить это можно убрав использование `Form Data` из `main.js`, т.е. оправлять запрос обычными средствами браузера, тогда он будет отправляться как `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, и `body-parser` его прекрасно поймет (`multipart/formdata` вам тут не нужен, он в основном используется при передаче файлов).

Или если же нужно отправлять как `Form Data`, то можно поставить один из пакетов перечисленных на `GitHub`, например `multer`:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();

app.post("/register", upload().none(), function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("Works!");
})
```