# Как в post запросе fetch отправить объект FormData

Tags: javascript

ДД, подскажите как отравлять данные из формы с помощью formdata?пересмотрел пару тройку статей и ничего не получилось отправить, постоянно этот объект пустой, пример

```
 <form action="" id="reg">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="ssername" />
   <input type="number" placeholder="Age" id="age" />
   <label for="status">Status</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="status" />
   <button type="submit" id="btn">sumbit</button>
 </form>
```

```
const my_form = document.getElementById("reg");
my_form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(this);
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/create", {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "cors",
        body: data,
    })
   .then((res) => res.text())
   .then((data) => console.log(data));
});
```

Хочется понять как это работает, помогите пож-та если как правильно это сделать.

Comment: как ты проверяешь пустоту объекта?

Comment: не проверяю, я честно говоря вообще не понял как с этим конструктором работать.

Comment: Я имел ввиду: почему ты думал что этот объект пустой?

Comment: в пост запросе formdata не имела вложенностей, а не подскажешь как его на express потом обработать, развернул лог запроса с клиента и не вижу там этих данных

Comment: например так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1065494/186999

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для добавления полей из тега `form` в `FormData` у поля должно быть установлен атрибут `name`

В примере в вопросе установлен атрибут `id`, а атрибут `name` отсутствует.

Для решения нужно либо заменить `id` на `name`,  либо просто добавить `name` с нужным значением.

```js
const my_forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");
my_forms.forEach(my_form => my_form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData(this);
  console.log([...data.entries()]);
}));
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="ssername" />
  <input type="number" placeholder="Age" id="age" />
  <label for="status">Status</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="status" />
  <button type="submit" id="btn">sumbit</button>
</form>

<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="ssername" />
  <input type="number" placeholder="Age" name="age" />
  <label for="status">Status</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="status" />
  <button type="submit" id="btn">sumbit</button>
</form>
```